# java stream collect function giving error

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

First statement works but not second giving below error, why ?

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5).stream()
                                  .map(n -> n+1)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
                              .map(n -> n + 1)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

ERROR:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector<Object,capture#5-of ?,List<Object>> 
to Supplier<R>
```

Comment: Because `IntStream` is a stream of primitive `int` values, not boxed `Integer` values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While there is a `collect` method on a `Stream` which accepts a `Collector`, there is no such method on an `IntStream`.

You can convert your `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` using the `boxed()` method.

Answer (score 8):

The first statement produces a `Stream<Integer>` which has a `collect` method that takes a `Collector`.

The second statement produces an `IntStream` which does not have a `collect` method.

In order for the second statement to work,
you must convert the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` as follows:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
                              .map(n -> n + 1)
                              .boxed()
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or you can produce an `int` array instead of a `List<Integer>`:

```
int[] array = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
                       .map(n -> n + 1)
                       .toArray();
```

Comment: You can also use `mapToObj` instead of `map(…).boxed()`.